# Dictionary give the values to the certain key, but the others get the same values

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary to record the accurancy when I run the program.There are some problem when I give the values to the certain key

Here, I create a dictionary to record the accurancy when it trains or validate

```
acc = dict.fromkeys(['train', 'val'], dict.fromkeys(['pa', 'iou', 'dice'], 0))
```

The original dictionary looks like this

```
{'train': {'pa': 0, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0}, 'val': {'pa': 0, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0}}
```

Now, I give the some values for testing

```
acc['train']['pa'] = 0.9
acc['train']['iou'] = 0.8
acc['train']['dice'] = 0.7
```

**The problems is all the values in key `val` becomes the same**

```
{'train': {'pa': 0.9, 'iou': 0.8, 'dice': 0.7}, 'val': {'pa': 0.9, 'iou': 0.8, 'dice': 0.7}}
```

Comment: Obviously the problem is not there, because what you show works fine: https://repl.it/repls/YummyFaithfulWatchdog

Comment: sorry, I edit the article and you can try again

Comment: You only have *a single* dict that gets assigned to *both* train and val.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the provided value is a mutable object (whose value can be modified) like list, dictionary, etc., when the mutable object is modified, each element of the sequence also gets updated.
This is because, each element is assigned a reference to the same object (points to the same object in the memory).

In your problem, `dict.fromkeys(['pa', 'iou', 'dice'], 0)` returns a dictionary which is mutable type, so each element is assigned to the same object.

To avoid this issue, you can use dictionary comprehension.

```
from copy import copy
# keys
keys = ['train', 'val']
value = dict.fromkeys(['pa', 'iou', 'dice'], 0 )

acc = { key : copy(value) for key in keys }

print(acc)

# updating the value
acc['train']['pa'] = 2 
print(acc)
```

Source: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/fromkeys

Comment: Sorry, how can I know a list/dictionary which is mutable type?

Comment: List and dictionary are always mutable types, tuple, integers etc.. are non-mutable types. If you like to know whether a particular type is mutable or not, refer to python documentation.

Comment: this article https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747 summarizes it well

Answer (score 1):

That's because `dict.fromkeys(['pa', 'iou', 'dice'], 0)` is called exactly once, not once for each key in `acc`.

```
>>> acc['train'] is acc['val']                                                  
True
```

The dictionaries are the same object in memory, you just have two ways to access it - via `acc['train']` and `acc['val']`.

You could use a `defaultdict` with a function that creates a new dictionary on demand:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict                                         
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: {'pa': 0, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0})                     
>>> d['train']                                                                  
{'pa': 0, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0}
>>> d['val']                                                                    
{'pa': 0, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0}
>>> d['train']['pa'] = 1                                                        
>>> d['train']                                                                  
{'pa': 1, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0}
>>> d['val']                                                                    
{'pa': 0, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0}
```

However, be aware that this creates a new dictionary each time you access a new key:

```
>>> d['foo']                                                                    
{'pa': 0, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0}
```

If you don't want that, create a dictionary for each key manually with a dict comprehension:

```
>>> keys = ['train', 'val']                                                     
>>> d = {k:{'pa': 0, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0} for k in keys}
>>> d['train']['pa'] = 1                                                        
>>> d['train']                                                                  
{'pa': 1, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0}
>>> d['val']                                                                    
{'pa': 0, 'iou': 0, 'dice': 0}
```

Comment: How can I know which situation will happen like this - **The list/dictionaries are the same object in memory, you just have two ways to access it**. It took me a while to find this bug. I don't want it happen again

Comment: @ntust_Ian It's in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) of the `fromkeys` method.